# SWI Prolog - Using a predicate with another predicate

Tags: prolog

I'm relatively new to prolog, and I'll try and explain this the best I can. Say that I have a small knowledge base of restaurants, where it has the name, cuisine, and price.

```
restaurant(spaghetti, italian, 20).
restaurant('naan bread', indian, 30).
...
```

And I have some people that like certain restaurants, such as:

```
likes(adam, restaurant, italian).
```

Where Adam likes italian restaurants. The main issue I'm having is that if I do a query such as:

```
likes(adam, spaghetti).
```

or

```
likes(adam, _, spaghetti).
```

It only comes up with false, no matter what I put. I have done a lot of research, but can't seem to get it to work - since I'm newish at prolog I don't really understand it. I have looked at books like 'Programming in Prolog' by Clocksin and Mellish and various websites, but I can't seem to find an answer or one I understand.

Comment: You can construct a predicate that calls the two predicates `restaurant` and `likes`, a bit similar to how a `JOIN` works in SQL.

Comment: Where did you get the question for this? Was it from a book or class? There is probably more facts in the database and you need to list them all here so we can help you.

Comment: You probably need to add a rule such as `likes(X, Dish) :- likes(X, restaurant, Cuisine), restaurant(Dish, Cuisine, _).` Prolog isn't a mind reader, it can't tell that someone likes a dish just because they like the cuisine without you informing it.

Comment: @GuyCoder yeah, it's from a class, but it's only a knowledge base of restaurants. So there aren't any other rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment

> It's only a knowledge base of restaurants. So there aren't any other rules.

we'll take it from there and start with the given rules.

```
restaurant(spaghetti, italian, 20).
restaurant('naan bread', indian, 30).
```

Next is the query you are trying

```
likes(adam, spaghetti).
```

Which is valid, but as we note in the comments some facts are missing.

The simplest fact to make the query correct would be

```
likes(adam, spaghetti).
```

but you have other queries like

```
likes(adam, restaurant, italian).
```

and facts like

```
restaurant('naan bread', indian, 30).
```

which suggest that you are aware that there are relationships between the four entities, `adam`, `itialian` and `spaghetti`, `20` (price).

There are endless ways to make relationships but for this example we will keep it more on the simple side.

```
person(adam).
person(mary).

food_nationality(spaghetti, italian).
food_nationality(hamburger, americian).
food_nationality('naan bread', indian).

food_price(spaghetti, 20).
food_price(hamburger, 30).
food_price('naan bread', 30).

likes(adam,italian).
likes(mary,american).
```

Now that we have some facts if you wanted to know what it cost for adam to eat a food he likes we start with the facts and see what we can conclude.

We see the fact

```
person(adam).
```

but that only tells us adam is a person and doesn't lead to any more information for our question.

We also see the fact

```
likes(adam,italian).
```

which tells us that adam likes italian but doesn't give us a specific food.

We also see

```
food_nationality(spaghetti, italian).
```

So we know adam likes italian and italian has spagehetti but we still need a price.

We also see

```
food_price(spaghetti, 20).
```

So we know adam likes italian and italian has spagehetti and spaghetti cost 20. So the answer is that for adam to eat something he likes it will cost 20.

As a Prolog predicate it would be

```
cost_to_eat(Person,Price) :-
   likes(Person,Nationality),
   food_nationality(Food, Nationality),
   food_price(Food, Price).
```

and running that for adam

```
?- cost_to_eat(adam,Price).
Price = 20.
```

It also works for mary

```
?- cost_to_eat(mary,Price).
Price = 30.
```

and it also works if you give just a price

```
?- cost_to_eat(Person,20).
Person = adam ;
false.
```

and it also works it you ask

```
?- cost_to_eat(Person,Cost).
Person = adam,
Cost = 20 ;
Person = mary,
Cost = 30.
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's just say you have the following facts, as suggested in your question, with no extra and no changes:

```
restaurant(spaghetti, italian, 20).
restaurant('naan bread', indian, 30).

likes(adam, restaurant, italian).
```

Now you'd like to ask the question "What dish does Adam like?"

We can add this simple rule:

```
likes(Person, Dish) :-
    likes(Person, restaurant, Type),
    restaurant(Dish, Type, _).
```

Now you can go ahead and ask the following:

```
?- likes(adam, Dish), write(Dish).
```

This spits out the answer `spaghetti`.